# Soap Parsing java based wsdl url no response in Android

Tags: android

I have a WSDL java based webservice and an android project.I didnt get any response from that wsdl url.

I couldn't solve this problem.

Here is Android Code Part.

try
            {

```
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject( "http://keycloud.noip.me:8081/knowledgecenterservice/webservice/ContentManagementService" , "getImageFromDistrict " );
            request.addProperty( "district" , "Bangalore" );

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope( SoapEnvelope.VER11 );
            new MarshalBase64().register( envelope ); //serialization
            envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.ENC;  
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject( request );

            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE( "http://keycloud.noip.me:8081/knowledgecenterservice/webservice/ContentManagementService" );
            transport.call( "http://keycloud.noip.me:8081/knowledgecenterservice/webservice/ContentManagementService/getImageFromDistrict" , envelope );
            SoapObject value = ( SoapObject ) envelope.getResponse();


            text.setText(value.toString());

            dialog.dismiss();

        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Post the full "xmlresponse" and "exception" log.

Comment: Hi @b1izzard                                                  Service name: getImageFromDistrict

Soap Request:

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservice.ekrishi.keyfalcon.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:getImageFromDistrict>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>Bangalore</arg0>
      </web:getImageFromDistrict>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Hi @b1izzard  Soap Reponse:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  
         <return>
            <image>ImageByteArraY1</image>
     <image>ImageByteArraY2</image>
     <image>ImageByteArraY3</image>
            <image>ImageByteArraY4</image>
            <image>ImageByteArraY5</image>
            <news>news1</news>
            <news>news2</news>
            <news>news3</news>
            <news>news4</news>
         </return>
      </ns1:getImageFromDistrictResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: Hi @Vamshi please help me to resolve errors

Comment: pleae check this webservice from .net side..is it valid or not?

Comment: Hi @dipali please tell me how to check its valid or not?

Comment: it will check by .net developer who build this webservice...

Comment: Have you copied the soap response properly? because the response you shared above does not contain any opening tag for `ns1:getImageFromDistrictResponse` and `soap:Body`...

Comment: HI @user1226136  Soap Reponse:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:getImageFromDistrictResponse xmlns:ns1="http://webservice.ekrishi.keyfalcon.com/">
         <return>
            <image>ImageByteArraY1</image>
     
            <news>news4</news>
         </return>
      </ns1:getImageFromDistrictResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: I think the error is with the line "androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);" you must specify the soap action i.e targetnamespace.

Comment: @Priyan Use soapUI standalone or as a eclipse plugin to test your request and response.

Comment: Hi@b1izzard In my wsdl there is no soap action then how can i use soap action in androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);

Comment: @Priyan, above soap response looks good. I suggest you edit your question to add the request/response (and any other relevant info). Will help people to have a clear understanding of your question at a glance...

Comment: @Priyan : Check my answer below. Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
 androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);
```

to

```
androidHttpTransport.call(METHOD_NAME, envelope);
```

**To check the response from server**

Install `SOA Client` Add-on on Mozilla Firefox.

I checked the response from server using the above specified URL i.e

```
http://keycloud.noip.me:8081/ekrishi/webservice/TestService?wsdl
```

and I happen to see that the method is not requesting for any parameters/inputs. So I don't know why did you wirte this line `request.addProperty("district","Bangalore");`

And I just invoked that method without any parameters and I got the error

**faultcode: soap:Server** -->`means there's a problem on server side. So check with the person who has written this webservice.`

**faultstring: Fault occurred while processing.**

Hope this information is useful for you :)

**EDIT** I have attached the snapshot of the error I got using SOA client. If everything is fine on server side, we will not get any error. I strongly believe that there's a problem on server side. Check your URL once.

[image: Error while parsing using SOA Client.]

```
See here the method is not requesting for any parameters. So no need to add -- request.addProperty("district", "Bangalore");. Below is the screenshot of that.
```

[image: It parameters needed.]

**I feel like the URL you are using in wrong. Cross check it once.**

Comment: Hi Aniruddha Thanks for your valuable answer will check it again and i will get back to you.

Comment: Hi @Aniruddha developer said there's no problem on server side.PLease check your code in android nu.

Comment: Hi @Aniruddha androidHttpTransport.call(METHOD_NAME, envelope); its not working

Comment: @Priyan See my edited answer. Usually URL will end with asmx while using .net webservices but yours in ending with wsdl. I'm bit confused about it.

Comment: @Priyan When you solve it, let me know what caused this problem.

Comment: HI @Aniruddha ok sure

Comment: @Priyan did you solve this problem? If yes, then what was it and how did you solve?

Comment: ,Still i didnt get a solution.

Comment: Hi @Aniruddh i changed the url please check it wheather the wsdl url correct or not.Developer said webservice developed in java.

Comment: @Priyan Give me the URL.

Comment: Hi i changed some modification in code please check it above ....http://keycloud.noip.me:8081/knowledgecenterservice/webservice/ContentManagementService?wsdl

Comment: I checked but still the same error. Why don't you request web service developer to go through this post? And follow the steps in my answer to know whether you are getting any response from server or not.

Comment: At least for this much effort you should accept my answer.